# Windows Server, Apache HTTP Server and MySQL configuration odd?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, windows-server-2008, xampp

It is poor form to have Apache running on a windows server and connected to a MySQL database?  I've heard that MySQL is better in a linux environment.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I wouldn't say it is bad form at such, but using specifically Apache on windows is more prone to problems. Although in my experience I have found no real problems using windows, the only real downside is that the initial hardware requirements are greater since windows has a lot of rubbish running in the background.

MySQL runs just fine on windows and the management interface is very good.

Comment: I'm quite pleased with the interface, like you said.  I'd like to use linux but with everything else I need to learn, not sure if now is the right time to learn a completely new OS let alone a public facing site.  If it was on a LAN, that might be okay.  Plus the file names are case-sensitive on Linux (to my understanding) and we cannot be 100% confident that the developers kept the file names consistent in the link that reference those file names (I hope that makes sense to someone else who might be reading this).

Comment: Can you run MySQL Server 64-bit on an apache 32-bit web server?  I've only found un-signed 64bit apache installers.

Comment: MySQL doesn't run on Apache. They are separate programs. So you can use either. Yes file names are case sensitive on Linux so if you can't be sure that the files are linked properly then it might be better to use windows. Especially if that's what you are used to using.

Comment: What is your reasoning behind using Apache rather than IIS?

Comment: Familiarity, mainly.  There are some URL rewrite rules that are needed.  Can IIS do that?

Comment: Yes, IIS has lots of _plugins_ for example [URL-Rewrite](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite)